# Angular JS Nested Array Object as HTML value

Tags: angularjs

I have this data:

```
Continent":"Asia",
"Countries":{
            "Japan":[
                {
                    "Id":"1",
                    "ColumnName":"Osaka",
                    "Type":"Label", } ] }
```

I wanted to use the id and type as HTML tag attribute value like:

```
if label:

"<label> {{ColumnName}} </label>"

if textbox:

"<input type="text" value"Osaka">"

if dropdown:

"<select>
  <option value="Osaka">Osaka</option> </select>"
```

Is that possible?

Thanks for all the ideas you can share! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is defined in your controller as

```
$scope.data = {
    "Continent":"Asia",
    "Countries":{
        "Japan":[
            {
                "Id":"1",
                "ColumnName":"Osaka",
                "Type":"Label", 
            }]
        }
    }
```

Then you can access these in your html like so:

```
<label>{{data.Countries.Japan[0].ColumnName}}</label>
<input type="text" ng-value"{{data.Countries.Japan[0].ColumnName}}">
<select>
    <option ng-value="{{data.Countries.Japan[0].ColumnName}}">{{data.Countries.Japan[0].ColumnName}}</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for that webernado, but what if it's not always a dropdown? What if it can be a label, a textbox?

Comment: If you would like a list of labels or textboxes you can use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop over the array of countries and display the ColumnName for each.